# Laravel 8 controller doesn't recognize JavaScript utility

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building a site with Laravel 8 and trying to pass PHP variables into JavaScript. At first I was using this kind of construction in my Blade file:

```
<script>
  let x = {{ $x }};
</script>
```

but this gets mangled by the format-on-save action in VSCode because the braces get interpreted as JavaScript and separated by spaces.

As an alternative, I've tried to install Laracasts/Utilities, following the instructions [here](https://packagist.org/packages/laracasts/utilities). After carrying out all the steps, however, the controller doesn't recognize `JavaScript`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
...
use JavaScript;               // <--- no info on mouseover

class XController extends Controller
{
  public function f()
  {
    JavaScript::put([...]);   // <--- Undefined type 'JavaScript'
```

I'm a beginner at PHP and Laravel, so this is beyond me. It seems that the alias isn't working properly (even though I listed it in `aliases` in `config/app.php`) based on the fact that no information pops up when I mouse over `use JavaScript` in VSCode. I've tried running magic commands like `php artisan optimize:clear`, `php artisan config:clear`, and `composer dump-autoload`, but they didn't change anything and maybe aren't relevant. What else can I try at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is easy way to pass php variable to  tag, however I'm also not much experienced and I feel like it is kind of a workaround.
So there are 2 simple steps:

1. In your blade add:

   <input id="x" type="hidden" value="{{ $x }}>
2. In the script get element value:

   var x = document.getElementById("x").value